# Unknown column in field list during select query after column deleted

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I keep getting an error message when I run a basic select query - not an insert or update - that tells me there is an unknown column in field list.

At one point there was a column by the name that the error is referring to but I have since restructured the database and there is no longer a column in that table by that name.

Interestingly enough this error only happens if I query the database from PHP. If I run a query directly on the server (using the SQL tab in phpMyAdmin) I get no error.

It sounds to me like there's a cache somewhere that I don't know about that needs to be cleared. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

As to the comment about using a framework. I'm not using anything fancy, just basic PHP/MySQL. An example of when I get the error would be

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$relation = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
return $relation;
```

even running a test query would return an error of unknown column in field list which is odd since I'm not actually looking for a specific column but just trying retrieve everything. I've never run into this issue before. Usually unknown column occurs when you try to insert something into a column (or update a column) that is not there.

Comment: never heard about that ! need really to be cleared !

Comment: When you said querying from `PHP`, I guess you use a framework. You probably need to inform your framework that your metadata has been modified.

Comment: I updated with an example

Comment: That example would not cause such as error.  Find the specific line of code where the error is thrown and post the specific query and error message you are getting.  Generally, this error message means exactly what it says - you are trying to access a column that does not exist.

Comment: Well that's the difficulty - I intentionally ran a select * query to test the problem. It does give me this error. I was trying to see if there was some reason that this could occurr other than a query that references a specific column. Is there any other possible reason you could think of for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon your server installation, both mySQL and PHP can be configured to do some pretty aggressive caching. Try sending a "reset query cache" command. This instructs mySQL to clear its query cache. If the problem still exists, then you are likely looking at something cached in PHP.

Comment: Where would something be cached in the PHP? I'm guessing this is realted to how PHP is actually set up on the server?

Comment: This isn't a problem related to query caching.